# Plex VPN port forwarded properly but not accessible

Tags: vpn, portforwarding, plex

TL;DR version at the bottom.

My ISP gives me a private IP (10 48 64 1) and I'm unable to do any port forwarding.

My setup: 
Debian Wheezy Linux headless Server

Asuswrt-merlin router(latest version)

AirVPN via Openvpn

With some reading, some VPN allow port forwarding to be done. So I went ahead with AirVPN and it worked great (for torrent). I tried to port forward Plex Media Server unfortunately it doesn't work.

[Port Forward in AirVPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8eYJ.png) (24253 is for torrent and 61477 is for Plex with local port of 32400)

[Even Plex says that it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnehx.png)

I was told to do some forwarding on IPtables on my router, so I went ahead with these codes (got it from AirVPN forum)

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -I FORWARD -i tun11 -p udp -d 192.168.2.140 --match multiport --dports 24253,32400,61477 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun11 -p tcp -d 192.168.2.140 --match multiport --dports 24253,32400,61477 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i tun11 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 24253,32400,61477 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.140
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i tun11 -p udp --match multiport --dports 24253,32400,61477 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.140
```

With this, somehow my router shows blank on the PREROUTING (but port is opened based on what I see from torrent and canyouseeme org)

With this everything should be set up, no problem and it be visible from outside, but unfortunately it doesn't. I tried from work to view my plex but it keeps saying 'connecting'.

All I can think now is the problem lies in the linux part (firewall maybe?)

I'm stuck for a few days and googling doesn't seem to help anymore.

Thanks for reading! I hope it can be solved.

TL;DR version

I'm connected to VPN but I have forwarded properly (canyouseeme org says it's opened) but Plex says cannot be viewed from outside network (keep connecting).

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I made the mistake by not changing the port back to 61477 which was for Plex. I used torrent's port and hence why it wasn't working.